# Pegar nome, nome do meio e sobrenome de registros do MySQL

Tags: mysql

Como posso recortar o nome de uma string vinda do MySQL para pegar nome, nome do meio e sobrenome, estou tentando e não estou conseguindo, o que tenho até agora é isso, mas preciso que o nome e o nome do meio fiquem juntos e sobrenome separado

```
SELECT
   SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Nome, ' ', 1), ' ', -1) AS first_name,
   If(length(Nome) - length(replace(Nome, ' ', '')) > 1,  
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Nome, ' ', 2), ' ', -1) ,NULL) 
           as NomeMeio,
   SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Nome, ' ', 3), ' ', -1) AS ÚltimoNome
FROM cadColaborador
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que preciso é isso:

```
Nome: ABEL DE
Sobrenome: CAMARGO
```

Comment: Como pretende diferenciar sobrenomes compostos de nomes do meio?

Comment: Se eu você você, eu trocava a estrutura dessa sua tabela, em vez de criar uma tabela com os campos "nome, nome do meio e sobrenome", crie uma tabela só com o nome e sobrenome. Se a pessoa tem um nome do meio como "João Paulo", adicione no campo nome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui fazer o que estava precisando, pegar nome, nome do meio e sobrenome de registros diretamente de uma query do MySQL, segue código para futuras pesquisas.

```
SELECT
 TRIM(SUBSTRING(`cadColaborador`.Nome, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(`cadColaborador`.Nome) - 
 CHAR_LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REVERSE(`cadColaborador`.Nome), ' ', 1)))) AS PrimeiroNome,
 REVERSE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REVERSE(`cadColaborador`.Nome), ' ', 1)) AS UltimoNome,
```

Comment: Apenas uma dúvida: se o último sobrenome for, por exemplo, Junior, Filho, Neto, etc, você vai mesmo assim considera-los como sobrenome?

Comment: Olá @anonimo, sim, pelas regras estipuladas aqui posso considerar, sem problema.